# The second largest eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ positive semidefinite real matrix with the trace of $A$ is $2$. Suppose there exist unit vectors $y,z$ satisfying $|Ay|=|Az|=1$ and $y\cdot z=0$.
How is it showed that the second largest eigenvalue of $A$ is greater than or equal to $1$?

Comment: Please don't modify your question in a way that invalidates existing answers, especially when the answers have received up-votes.

Comment: Sorry. I modified again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's false. Let $A=diag(\sqrt{2},0,2 - \sqrt{2})$. Let $y = (\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}, \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}, 0)$, $z = (\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}, - \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}, 0)$. The conditions are satisfied, while the second largest eigenvalue is $2 - \sqrt2 < 1$.

Comment: Thank you. Then, how about the case replacing the condition $|Ay|=1$ and $|Az|=1$ with ${}^t yAy={}^t zAz=1$?

Comment: @Ichiko, if by $ ^ty$ you mean $y^\top$, almost the same example will work (even a bit simpler).

Comment: Sorry, I can't make a counterexample to the case with the new conditon.

Comment: @Ichiko, sorry, but I won't answer that one: it's really simple modification, please do it yourself (I was already reluctant to answer to the original question since you didn't show any attempt). Try to substitute the current example and see how exactly it fails.